# String special char

Tags: java, encoding

I'm trying to get this string correctly valuated:

```
String s4 = "Entraîneur";
String s4a = new String(s4.getBytes("iso-8859-1"));
```

The value at runtime  is :

```
EntraÃ?Â®neur
```

Cannot understand

Thankss

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: why not use UTF8?

Comment: `String(byte[] bytes)`  Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the **platform's default charset**. So use `String(byte[] bytes,
      Charset charset)` if you want to pass the right charset.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a string with one encoding (the default one, most likely UTF-8 unless you've specified otherwise), and then reading it back in with a different, incompatible encoding (ISO 8859-1). This will almost always create problems with any non-ansii characters, as the different encodings represent these characters with different byte sequences.

If you want a (poor) analogy, it's a bit like printing out some Latin, then passing it to someone who only speaks English and asking what it means. You might be able to work some of it out, but other bits of it will come out as nonsense.

If you change the code to use the default charset:

```
String s4 = "Entraîneur";
String s4a = new String(s4.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
```

...then `s4a` should contain the correct value.

Comment: In Java, UTF-16 is the native String encoding.

Comment: @DPenner1 On second thoughts, isn't that just Java's internal encoding? I didn't think that necessarily reflected the runtime default... (I'm splitting hairs of course, the answer is basically the same regardless as to what the default encoding actually is.) I *used* to know this stuff like the back of my hand...

Comment: @DPenner1 In Java, text is canonically represented as sequences of char values. That is different to UTF-16, which, as all general-purpose character encodings, has no notion of Java char, and only translates from and to bytes. Notably there are two different UTF-16 encodings, one for each endianness. A concept that wouldn't make sense in Java. Java's canonical representation of text only reminds UTF-16, in that is uses the same mechanism of surrogate pairs to represent characters of code point greater than U+FFFF. Also, internally, Java plans to allow itself to choose between encodings.

Comment: @DPenner1 Actually I'd say that for the purpose of the question, users of the class String shouldn't care how the class String has chosen to implement the representation of text. It does its job, and its job is not related to character encoding in any way whatsoever. Especially since in Java 11 they intend to represent ASCII compatible Strings as ASCII. The distinction I was trying to make, is that UTF-16 uses bytes, and Java uses chars. Still, if the doc chooses to explain it that way too, I won't argue -_-°

Comment: @kumesana Upon careful re-reading of the question, I agree and removed a few of my previous comments. Time for me to go get some coffee...